# comparing to arrays and returning the item that's missing?

Tags: c

I am not sure why I am not able to get this right, I spend some time on this, and I don't get what I want. and now I am upset. I have a list LL[] of desired items, and a list seenLL[] which may contain items from LL[], but in any random order. I wanted to put the missing items in unseen[] and then print unseen. At-least that is my idea :(

```
unsigned int i=0, j=0, k=0;
unsigned int LL[] = {0xB173,0xB193,0xB14D,0xB14E};  //Desired items
unsigned int seenLL[5];  // Seen items
unsigned int unseen[5];  // For unseen items

printf("\n List of Logcodes seen in filtered view :");      
for(i=0;i<view->numFilters;i++){   // I can't explain this, as it's BIG
    if(flt->filterType == LOGCODE_TYPE ){ 
        printf(" 0x%04X,",flt->code);  // This will print the list of items in the view. Usually about 2 or 3 items
        seenLL[k]=flt->code;   // Copy them to seenLL[]
        k++;
     }
 } 
 k=0;
 // At this point though my seenLL[] has a few of my desired items, it also contains junk information, which I am unable to explain.

for(i=0;i<sizeof(LL)/sizeof(LL[0]);i++){
    for(j=0;j<sizeof(seenLL)/sizeof(seenLL[0]);j++){
        if(LL[i] != seenLL[j]){
            unseen[k]=LL[i];    // I was trying to copy to unseen[] items that are missing from the desired list LL[]
            k++;
        }
        //else{       // Dumb, but what if seenLL[] had items from LL[] but not in the same order as they are in the array LL[], it can occur in any order
         // if(sizeof(unseen)/sizeof(unseen[0])!=0)
        //      if(LL[i] == unseen[i]{ 
        //            k--;
        //            unseen[i]=0;
         //       }                     
    }
}
if(k>0) printf(" Missing Logs Pkts :");
if(k>0) for(i=0;i<sizeof(unseen)/sizeof(unseen[0]);i++)    //sigh! my pathetic attempt to print missing items.
     printf("%d,",unseen[i]);
```

Comment: Please keep you lines of code shorter to make the code fit in the frame.

Comment: That kind of task is very easy if you sort the array first.

Answer (score 0):

You must scan the `seenLL` array for each element of `LL` but properly detect if the element has been seen:

```
for (i = 0;i < sizeof(LL) / sizeof(LL[0]); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < sizeof(seenLL) / sizeof(seenLL[0]); j++) {
        if (LL[i] == seenLL[j])
            break;
    }
    if (j >= sizeof(seenLL) / sizeof(seenLL[0])) {
        unseen[k++] = LL[i];    // scan went to the end, no match.
    }
}
```

I suggest using the macro `countof` to clarify your code:

```
#define countof(a)  ((sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
```

Comment: ah, this makes more sense. I can try it this way, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong.

What you're doing: For each item in `LL`: if it is different from *some* item in `seenLL`, add it to `unseen`.

What you should do: For each item in `LL`: if it is different from *every* item in `seenLL`, add it to `unseen`.

(Another way to think of these two possible logics: the first one checks for some item whether it is the same as every item in `seenLL`, while the second one checks whether it is the same as some item in `seenLL`. It's clear that the first check cannot succeed if `seenLL` contains at least two different items.)

Comment: I see. yeah, thats something i can do.

Answer (score 0):

Array `seenLL` has space for only five elements, but there's nothing to suggest or ensure that the number of codes you attempt to record in it will be five or fewer if `LL` had more than five elements.

Furthermore, after you are done populating `seenLL`, you discard the value of variable `k`, which tells you how many of the elements of `seenLL` actually contain valied data.

Later, you test each element of `LL` against potentially *all* the elements of `seenLL`, possibly including some that do not contain valid data.  In fact, you should test against all valid elements but no invalid ones, else you are likely to turn up all elements as unseen (they will fail to match at least one element of `seenLL`).

Array `unseen` also has space for only five elements, but there's nothing to suggest or ensure that the number of codes you attempt to record in it will be five or fewer.

Then, at the end, if you in fact did recognize any unseen elements, you print *every* element of `unseen`, likely including some that do not contain valid data.

Comment: `seenLL[]` will be always a subset of `LL[]`, and I limited the numbers here so that it would be easier to explain.

I discarded `k` thinking that it would have the offset, and not the count of items in `seenLL[]`, but I now see the error in my ways.